# CLIQUE $\leq_p$ SAT

Tags: satisfiability, clique, polynomial-time-reductions

i'm trying to reduce CLIQUE to SAT:

- Given: Graph G=(Vertices V, Edges E) and $k \in \mathbb{N}$
- Output: Formular F such that if G contains a complete subgraph of size k, the formular is satisfiable (and vice versa).

I tried doing it the way Cook/Levin showed that SAT is NP-complete by introducing a set of booleans $v_i$ for each vertex and $e_{i, j}$ for an edge going from $v_i$ to $v_j$. Now if $v_i$ is part of the clique, then $e_{i, j}$ must be true iff $v_j$ is also in the clique.

So we can conclude, that $v_i \land v_j \implies e_{i, j}$ and this is for true for at least $i, j \in \{0, ..., k - 1\}$ and $i \neq j$. Also we need to make sure that no edge that doesn't exist can be set to true: 
$\bigwedge_{(i, j)\notin E} \lnot\, e_{i, j}$.

I don't know if im on the correct way or if I might miss something.

1. How would I restrict the formular $v_i \land v_j \implies e_{i, j}$ to be true for at least k variables?
2. Is this way in poly-time?
3. Is there any better way?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are trying to reduce clique to SAT and not the other way around? Assuming your goal is establishing NP-completeness of clique, usually one proves it by showing clique is in NP (a rather trivial matter) followed by establishing a reduction from 3SAT to clique (using appropriate graph gadgets).

Comment: Also note that, although not very enlightening, you can achieve what you want by constructing an NTM for clique and then using the construction from the [Cook-Levin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook-Levin_theorem) on said NTM. This might be the fastest (or laziest) way of obtaining the reduction.

Comment: Yes I know that for normal people do it the other way around. I was just trying to challenge me as in a video i was watching the it said that the way CLIQUE <= SAT is easy to show. Constructing a NTM is easy indeed! I was just trying to exercise my reduction skills!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to reduce CLIQUE to SAT. Probably the simplest is as follows. Suppose that we have a graph $G = (V,E)$, and interested in a $k$-clique. We will have $k|V|$ variables $x_{iv}$, whose intended meaning is "the $i$th vertex of the clique is $v$". The constraints are:

- There is an $i$th vertex: for all $1 \leq i \leq k$, $\bigvee_{v \in V} x_{iv}$.
- The $i$th and $j$th vertices are different: for all $1 \leq i < j \leq k$ and $v \in V$, $\lnot x_{iv} \lor \lnot x_{jv}$.
- Any two vertices in the clique are connected: for all $1 \leq i < j \leq k$ and $v,u \in V$ such that $(v,u) \notin E$, $\lnot x_{iv} \lor \lnot x_{ju}$.

Comment: thank you yuval so much!

Comment: but i still didnt understand , can you add a drawing ? of the reduction ? please

Comment: You will learn more by creating such a drawing yourself.

Comment: i dont understand the notation x_iv what does it mean ?  xiv, whose intended meaning is "the ith vertex of the clique is v"

Comment: It’s just the name of a variable. The variables are indexed by two indices, $i$ and $v$.